# Given a GUID, if i shorten it .. can we assume it will still be unique?

Tags: language-agnostic, guid

Given that `GUID's` are (more or less) unique, if we shorten it [with some code](http://madskristensen.net/post/a-shorter-and-url-friendly-guid) which:

> > It basically just converts a GUID into a base64 string and shortens it a bit.
> >     It takes a standard GUID like this:
> >
> > **c9a646d3-9c61-4cb7-bfcd-ee2522c8f633**
> >
> > And converts it into this smaller string:
> >
> > **00amyWGct0y_ze4lIsj2Mw**

Can I now assume that the shortened guid is equally as unique as it's previous (normal) form?

Comment: Given that it states `decodes the string back to the original GUID again`, I would guess yes - base64 is more concise than hex and the the base64 trailer is trimmed. Obviously this is for presentation tier only - storing the Guid in .Net as 22 chars (44 bytes) vs the native 16 byte [`System.Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) probably isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

This is a reversable transform — you can get the original GUID back with an inverse function. That means that it's *exactly* as "unique"; there's a different "shortened GUID" for every GUID. The final `substr` step in the encode function is removing the base64 padding characters `==`. This doesn't lose any information because every GUID is the same length and therefore every GUID has the same padding. The decode function re-appends `"=="` before passing to the base64 decoder.

Comment: er. are you saying that this is unique, then .. because there is only one answer when we reverse this?

Comment: What I'm saying is that this is just another *representation* of the same information.